# How do I fix "incomprehensible buffer" error when running list-packages?

Tags: package-repositories

When running list-packages in emacs on an up-to-date Debian Buster (10.6) I get the following error:

`error in process sentinel: Error retrieving: https://stable.melpa.org/packages/archive-contents "incomprehensible buffer"`

The exact version of the emacs package is 1:26.1+1-3.2+deb10u1.  When using wget on that URL and looking at the downloaded file it looks like a valid e-lisp data structure to me.

This has been working in the past and works fine in the MacPorts emacs package version 27.1_5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solved it by adding the following to `init.el`

```lisp
    (setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
```

Comment: I couldn't find `init.el` and added it on `~/.emacs`, and it solved the problem.

Comment: This problem is discussed here: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=34341

Comment: Can you explain what this does?